# select specific variable from multiple sheet and write as comma separated text file in R?

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, tidyverse, write.table

I created `myData.xlsx` sheet. I want to extract `PCP`, `MinT`, and `MaxT` for each `variable (i.e., G1,G2..etc)` of `myData.xlsx` and write it as a `comma separated value` `text` file. The name of the `text` file should be the variable for which we are extracting the data (i.e., G1.txt, G2.txt...etc).

```
    library(tidyverse)
    library(xlsx)
    
set.seed(123)

    MaxT <- data.frame(G1= runif(1095,-5,20), G2= runif(1095,-4,18),G3= runif(1095,-5,15))
    MinT <- data.frame(G1= runif(1095,-10,10), G2= runif(1095,-8,10),G3= runif(1095,-15,10))
    PCP <- data.frame(G1= runif(1095,1,5), G2= runif(1095,2,10),G3= runif(1095,0,10))
    
    write.xlsx(MaxT, file="myData.xlsx", sheetName="MaxT", row.names=FALSE)
    write.xlsx(MinT, file="myData.xlsx", sheetName="MinT", append=TRUE, row.names=FALSE)
    write.xlsx(PCP, file="myData.xlsx", sheetName="PCP", append=TRUE, row.names=FALSE)
```

For example, the output for `G1.txt` should be something like this

```
PCP,MinT,MaxT
0.17,-10.82,-4.71
0.21,-11.87,-2.02
0.14,-4.42,0.04
0.21,-6.9,-0.3
0.13,-8.28,-1.68
0.19,-12.5,-8.53
0.29,-11.29,-8.19
0.3,-12.87,-7.05
0.07,-11.53,-5.14
```

Comment: for(c in colnames(MaxT)) write.csv(data.frame(MaxT = MaxT[[c]], MinT = MinT[[c]], PCP=PCP[[c]]), file = paste0(c,".txt") )  # does this help you?

Comment: Not really- i need to `read_excel(myData.xlsx)` and do the processing as needed.

Comment: @RicardoVillalba- I made your code work. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I tried a different way (I thought I could avoid the for loop). The idea was to make one big dataframe with all your data, then pivot it, nest it, and write the csv files in the end.
Not sure if it's better tho.

```
bind_rows(list(PCP = PCP, MaxT = MaxT, MinT = MinT), .id = "id") %>% 
pivot_longer(!id, names_to = "names", values_to = "values") %>% 
group_by(id, names) %>% 
nest() %>%
unnest_wider(data) %>% 
pivot_wider(names_from = id, values_from = values) %>%
unnest(cols = c(PCP, MaxT, MinT), names_repair = "universal") %>% 
nest() %>% 
by_row(~write.csv(.$data, file = paste(.$names, ".csv", sep = ""), row.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE))
```